# how to call a function with success and failure?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I've got a function:

```
func retrieveArticleWithTopic(topicId id: String, success: ([Newsfeed] -> Void), failure: (NSError -> Void)) {
    client.fetchEntries(["content_type": ContentType.Article.rawValue, "include": 10]) { (results) in
        // TODO: some more code will go here
        var feeds = [Newsfeed]()
        success(feeds)
    }
}
```

Which I need to pass a ID as a string to. Im struggling to call this function and pass values to it. I've tried:

```
ContentManager().retrieveTopics(TopicID:"Hello")
```

But I get an error that reads `Missing argument for parameter failure in call`.

How do pass a string to this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `success` and `failure` parameters are required (they don't have default values). You must pass two blocks:

```
retrieveTopics(topicID: "hello", success: { newsfeeds in
    print("retrieved \(newsfeeds)")
}, failure: { error in
    print("error: \(error)")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call like this:

```
retrieveArticleWithTopic(topicId: "", success: { (newsfeeds) in

    }) { (error) in

}
```

Or you don't want to handle success or failure, you can make it optional.

```
func retrieveArticleWithTopic(topicId id: String, success: ([Newsfeed] -> Void)?, failure: (NSError -> Void)?) {

}

retrieveArticleWithTopic(topicId: "", success: nil, failure: nil)
```